# make realpath() in c++ not to resolve symlink

Tags: c++, realpath

I am using this code to get absolute path of a file:

```
String getAbsolutePath(String x){
    char path[FILENAME_MAX+1];
    realpath(x.c_str(),path);
    return toString(path);

}
```

But the `realpath()` function resolves symlinks too. How can I **not** resolve the symlinks i.e get the path of the symlink itself (not the file pointed to by the link)?

Comment: Please perform _research_ before asking.